# Cannot click on checkboxes in yahoo mail using .NET WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms

In WinForms, I am attempting a very simple WebBrowser control use for yahoo mail. I am using the WebBrowser component in vs2010.  First, I load up a page:

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://mail.yahoo.com");
```

Then I am attempt to select all the items in my email:

```
private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Select checkboxes containing the word "this" (Select this email)
  foreach (HtmlElement oCheckBox in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
  {
    if (oCheckBox.GetAttribute("type").ToLower() == "checkbox")
    {
      if (oCheckBox.OuterHtml.ToLower().Contains("this"))
      {
        //oCheckBox.SetAttribute("value", "Yes");  //did not work
        //oCheckBox.SetAttribute("value", "1");    //did not work
        //oCheckBox.InvokeMember("Click");         //did not work
        oCheckBox.InvokeMember("CLICK");           //did not work
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Tried all of the above and none of them select the checkboxes.  Not sure if its particular to how the checkboxes in yahoo mail are setup?  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks Before Hand

Comment: Use your dev tools to check what kind what kind of elements they have,

Comment: The type of elements are "checkbox", it executes the "..InvokeMember("CLICK").." it just does not select the checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
private void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Select checkboxes containing the word "this" (Select this email)
  foreach (HtmlElement oCheckBox in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input"))
  {
    if (oCheckBox.GetAttribute("type").ToLower() == "checkbox")
    {
      if (oCheckBox.OuterHtml.ToLower().Contains("this"))
      {
        oCheckBox.SetAttribute("checked", "true");
      }
    }
  }
}
```